# Change number binding depending on class within Tkinter Frame

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, key-bindings

I have a Tkinter GUI that is comprised of several classes all contained within one frame. All the classes have the same dimensions and are all loaded simultaneously on top of one another. However, user input determines which class is visible. Each class has the same layout and number of buttons as the others. ie: 3x3 grid of buttons.

I've started implementing `.bind()` functions that associate each button with the respective key on the number pad. The problem is that the `.bind()` functions remain static throughout all the classes because of the **one** frame.

How would I add `.bind()` functions to the following script to adjust **depending** on the currently visible class? Effectively changing the commands in order to match up with the corresponding 3x3 button grid.

```
import subprocess
import Tkinter as tk

class MainApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(column=5, row=15)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nswe")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

        self.bind('0',(lambda event: self.show_frame(StartPage)))
        self.bind('1',(lambda event: self.show_frame(PageOne)))
        self.bind('2',(lambda event: self.show_frame(PageTwo)))

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        def randomfunction0():
            subprocess.Popen('foobar', shell=True)

        def randomfunction1():
            subprocess.Popen('foobar', shell=True)

        StartPageButton0 = tk.Button(self, compound="top", image=self.StartImage0, text="foobar0", fg="black", command=lambda: subprocess.Popen('foobar0', shell=True))
        StartPageButton1 = tk.Button(self, compound="top", image=self.StartImage1, text="foobar1", fg="black", command=lambda: subprocess.Popen('foobar1', shell=True))
        StartPageButton2 = tk.Button(self, compound="top", image=self.StartImage2, text="foobar2", fg="black", command=lambda: subprocess.Popen('foobar2', shell=True))

        StartPageButton0.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=10)
        StartPageButton1.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=20, pady=10)
        StartPageButton2.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=20, pady=10)

        controller.bind('1',(lambda event: subprocess.Popen('foobar0', shell=True)))
        controller.bind('2',(lambda event: subprocess.Popen('foobar1', shell=True)))
        controller.bind('3',(lambda event: subprocess.Popen('foobar2', shell=True)))

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        Page1Button0 = tk.Button(self, compound="top", image=self.Page1Image0, text="foobar0", fg="black", command=lambda: subprocess.Popen('foobar0', shell=True))
        Page1Button1 = tk.Button(self, compound="top", image=self.Page1Image1, text="foobar1", fg="black", command=lambda: subprocess.Popen('foobar1', shell=True))
        Page1Button2 = tk.Button(self, compound="top", image=self.Page1Image2, text="foobar2", fg="black", command=lambda: subprocess.Popen('foobar2', shell=True))

        Page1Button0.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=10)
        Page1Button1.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=20, pady=10)
        Page1Button2.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=20, pady=10)

        controller.bind('1',(lambda event: subprocess.Popen('foobar0', shell=True)))
        controller.bind('2',(lambda event: subprocess.Popen('foobar1', shell=True)))
        controller.bind('3',(lambda event: subprocess.Popen('foobar2', shell=True)))

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # PageOne Repeated with different subprocess.Popen commands.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.title("foobar title")
    app.mainloop()
```

While we are at it, the one Frame setup also doesn't allow me to change the title displayed at the top of the GUI window. Would I be able to change `app.title("foobar title")` within each class? Opposed to having just one title displayed across all classes.

EDIT: I've tried using `controller.bind()` and `self.bind()` however self.bind doesn't change anything. The initial bindings in the `MainApp()` class are what get executed regardless of page focus.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `self.bind` rather than `controller.bind`, the page-specific function should run, since only the page with focus will see the click. This is normally how you handle bindings -- only bind to the widgets that the bindings should apply to. In this case you don't want global bindings, you want bindings for each page.

The other solution is to bind them all to `controller.handleKey(1)`, `controller.handleKey(1)`, etc. `handleKey` is a generic function whose only function is to figure out which page is current, and call the `handleKey` of the current frame.

Comment: I've tried using `self.bind()` various different ways within each class with no luck. ie: One example I've tried is defining a function for each button. This contains the grid(), button(), etc... Then calling that buttons function (or executed command) through `.bind()` however, regardless of what I try, the initial bindings are the ones that get executed. Also, can you give me an example of where/how to use the handlekey() function. I can't find useful python references by searching and can't figure out how exactly to use them.

Comment: @bitinerary: `handlekey` is just a name I made up. You can call it whatever you want. The general idea is, the bindings call a common function, and the common function forwards the call to a specific page.